# How can I get information about a folder?

Tags: video, files, date

Someone copied a folder contains many video files to my laptop . I'd like to know when he copied them and some other information like this . I think accessed date and modified date are not always right ! Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what information you want exactly, but it also depends on the file system and how the file system is mounted (noatime).

Probably the best command to start with is stat

```
stat /home/bodhi/
File: `/home/bodhi/'
Size: 12288           Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 12h/18d Inode: 17          Links: 31
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/   bodhi)   Gid: ( 1000/   bodhi)
Access: 2011-12-21 10:08:22.411914000 -0700
Modify: 2011-12-21 10:03:52.748580667 -0700
Change: 2011-12-21 10:03:52.748580667 -0700
```

Some references for you :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/display-file-or-file-system-status.html

At the bottom of that page are a series of pages

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-file-system-part-i.html

The information is broken into several (7) short tutorials.

In a nut shell, by default, Ubuntu is going to trace when a file is accessed, modified, and changed but not when it was created. You can modify this behavior

From there the discussion become increasingly technical =)